# c# - Use the same element in different forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2013

I am doing a registration system. In this system I use a modal, another form that is displayed when the user clicks a button.
To show the form, I use:

```
private void btnShowModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddUserForm form = new AddUserForm();
    form.Show();
}
```

This works great to show the form. Now this is my problem: if I create one label in this form and try to use it for reference in the primary form I get the error that it does not exist in context. Example, I've created label1 in the AddUserForm. Now I will try to use the same label in Form1 to change the text:

```
label1.Text = "I was created in AddUserForm and now I'm at Form1!";
```

...but this don't work, I get the error:

```
The name 'label1' does not exist in the current context.
```

How I can use elements in both forms? I need to add a reference? How? Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Create a Base form that creates the label. Each form can then inherit from the base form and share it that way.

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{
  //define label

}


public AddUserForm : BaseForm
{
}
```

Comment: I'm trying:
`namespace Form1
{
    public class AddUserForm : Form1
    {
        public AddUserForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}`
But this is not working, the elements from Form1 isn't recognized by AddUserForm and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

In your AddUserForm, create this property:

```
public string LabelText
{
    get { return label1.Text; }
    set { label1.Text = value; }
}
```

Then in your Form1, simply add this line after you create the AddUserForm instance:

```
form.LabelText = "I was created in AddUserForm and now I'm at Form1!";
```

More generally, while you could have exposed the field (it's private by default), doing so is a bad idea. Wrapping form elements in properties gives you control over exactly what the outside world can and cannot change. For example, you may not want other classes being able to change the size, location, font, etc. of the label. Or maybe you do, but if so then you add properties specifically for those things you want to be able to be changed.

Comment: This not worked. There is no any way I add a reference to the elements of the first form? I will use it to register user and I will need some information from a list in Form1.

Comment: If you are more specific than just "this not worked", then the answer can be elaborated to deal with whatever specific issue you had. You can easily pass data from one object to another, once each object has a reference to the other. But it's important to preserve `encapsulation` and make sure that private data remains private to each object. Using properties as above is a good way to control access in this scenario and it will work as long as you use the technique correctly.

Comment: Well, this worked for the secondary form but no to principal.
If I use this on AddUserForm I can get the data from Form1 but not vice-versa. Example, this in Form1:
`public string labelREF
        {
            get { return label1.Text; }
            set { label1.Text = value; }
        }`
This in AddUserForm:
`Form1 principalform = new Form1();
principalform.label1 = "I was created in Form1 and will change my text to this by a click of a button in AddUserForm"`
For AddUserForm this works, but for Form1 not.

Comment: If the property you define in Form1 is named `labelREF`, then the property name you need to use needs to be `labelREF`, not `label1` as you say you're using. And _again_, when you write that something doesn't work, you need to be _specific_. How doesn't it work? What error message (if any) do you get?

Comment: I can't be more specific than this because I have no error message!
This just don't work with the primary form but work with AddUserForm, I can't understand this. I'm doing the same thing that works on AddUserForm with the Form1, but for this, the text of the label not change. I'm using `principalform.labelREF = "Text"` My code compiles well but nothing happens when I click on the button to display the text.

Comment: Certainly you can be more specific. You just _were_ more specific ("nothing happens when I click"), even if that's still insufficient information. If you don't want to post a complete code example that demonstrates the problem, then you should probably use the debugger to figure it out yourself. There is no question that if the line of code assigning a new value to the Text property were to execute, it would get new text. So for some reason, you're not getting to that line. At this point, it's not a problem with the technique you originally asked about...you just have some other bug as well.

Comment: I have found a best technique to do my purpose here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6525896%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
But this was being so strange... if I use to pass a data from Form1 to an element of AddUserForm works well! What I verified is when I pass from AddUserForm to Form1 the value is changed but the label in program still the same!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like this,

Form1.cs

```
private void btnShowModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(ref this.label1);
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form2.cs

```
    Label labelOne = null;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(ref Label lbl)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        labelOne = lbl;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelOne.Text = "A";
    }
```

Hope it solves!